# Adaptive Card Designer Custom tool palette

Tags: angular, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

How can I add the custom card element into Adaptive designer tool Palette when designer SDK loads into the browsers.

Comment: Are you talking about using the Designer SDK within your own website / App?

Comment: Did you check this already? -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards-designer

Comment: Yes, I am using the designer in my own website. I referred already and following the same. I need to add and remove the tool palette item from the designers

Comment: In the guide on npmjs.com, theres various explainations on how to do this. Its further down, need to scroll a lot. Theres examples on how to add buttons and also how to change the tool palette.

Comment: You are correct, I tried the sample that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/extensibility#extensibility-with-the-js-sdk-version-20-and-greater 
adding the custom element into the tool palette.
But, The added item not rendered in the tool palette.

Comment: Can you update your question with a code sample of what you tried? Sounds like a bug if it doesn't work while everything is done right.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: AC.GlobalRegistry.elements.register("ProgressBar", TextBlock); -- Used this code to register the new element as per the Document, but It not shows in the tool palette.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.